# Skip First Line Which is Header

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am using akka-stream to parse file. IN my file I have header row first and nowhere else. How can I skip this header file in my stream first? I do not want to check everytime if line is header or not. Is there a way to do this?

```
FileIO.fromPath(path).
  via(delimiter(ByteString("\n"), Int.MaxValue)). // split into lines
  map(_.decodeString("UTF-8")). // convert ByteStrings to Strings
  filter(!_.startsWith("#")). // remove comments
  fold(0)((i, _) => i + 1). // count remaining lines
  runForeach(println) // run the stream, print result
```

Comment: `.drop(1)`?....

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading a CSV file, you can use [Alpakka: Comma-Separated Values - CSV](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/data-transformations/csv.html#csv-conversion-into-a-map)

Example :

```
  Source
.single(ByteString(
  """eins,zwei,drei
    |11,12,13
    |21,22,23
    |""".stripMargin))
.via(CsvParsing.lineScanner())
.via(CsvToMap.toMap())
.fold(0)((i, _) => i + 1)
.runForeach(println)
```

outputs:`2`